# Apriori rules df requirements

Tags: r, associations, apriori

**Problem:**

Unable to generate apriori rules using `library(arules)` on PC. When I run the following function:

```
rules <- apriori(df, parameter = list(supp = 0.01, conf = 0.5))
```

RStudio throws back the following error:

> *Error in asMethod(object) :    column(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.*

**Suspected Solution:**

I am almost certain the dataset must be formatted to conform to `apriori`'s expected input.

**Dataset:**

[image: df]

**Code:**

```
#Load and install packages
#install.packages("arules")
library(arules)

#Assign to dataframe
df <- read.csv("C:/Titanic.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#generate rules
rules <- apriori(df, parameter = list(supp = 0.01, conf = 0.5))
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

```
#One solution on SO was to factor
df<- sapply(df, as.factor)
#failed.


#What if I discretize the columns?
df$Passenger <- discretize(df$Passenger)
#After discretizing this column and running apriori, still get an error.
df$Class <- discretize(df$Class)
#discretize does not work on column Class


#could column 1 be a problem? Try dropping it.
df$Passenger <- NULL
#this did not work!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your logic is correct, some fine adjustment is necessary only.

First of all, you need to read characters as factors which mean that `stringsAsFactors` should be switched on when reading your data:

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Titanic.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Then the problem should be with the first column only. If you want **to drop the first column**, you may do it directly in an argument of `apriory()`:

```
rules <- apriori(df[ , -1], parameter = list(supp = 0.01, conf = 0.5))
```

If you prefer **to handle the first column like a factor**, you make do like this

```
df$Passenger <- as.factor(df$Passenger)
```

Then your initial statement `rules <- apriori(df, parameter = list(supp = 0.01, conf = 0.5))` works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Ekatef. It might be my shortcomings with R, but it still throws the same error. I've also tried turning the dataset into a binary matrix, without any success. At this point, I'm growing skeptical of it merely being a technical problem with installation, as none of the online tutorials seem to work either...I'll keep slugging away and update, accordingly.

Comment: @graphicdezine I'm almost sure that the problem is with the data format: `stringsAsFactors` should be set `TRUE` when reading the data set. Sorry, I haven't noticed it before. The answer is updated now

Comment: I just ran the code and it seems to work. Next step is for me to understand how/why your solution worked. I'll further comment tonight, for future readers. Thank you!

Comment: As seen [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html), categorical variables are called factors in R. Because I was trying to load categorical variables, I needed to first convert them. As stated [here](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-r-for-finance/factors-4?ex=10#skiponboarding), "R's default behavior when creating data frames is to convert all characters into factors. This has caused countless novice R users a headache trying to figure out why their character columns are not working properly,..." Good luck and have fun!